# How to fix "cmake_pch.hxx" issue occurred from stdafx.h precompilation

Tags: c++11, cmake, ubuntu-22.04

There are two projects in my C++ solution. So, resultant of one project is the dependency for other project.

I have placed `ProjectA/src/Include` in `ProjectB` as `ProjectA` is a dependency for `ProjectB`. In `ProjectB/Src/stdafx.h` I have included that header file from `ProjectA/src/Include`.

I have included the `ProjectA/src/Include` in the CMake file as well and my CMake file of `ProjectB` look like:

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/ProjectA/include)
target_link_directories(ProjectB PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/ProjectA/lib)
target_link_libraries(ProjectB PRIVATE ProjectA)
```

I get the issue from this line:

```
target_precompile_headers(ProjectB PRIVATE
    "$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/stdafx.h>"
)
```

Issue: `Defs.h` is from `ProjectA/src/Include` and included in `ProjectB/Src/stdafx.h`.

```
In file included from /home/vsts/work/1/s/ProjectB/out/build/Linux-GCC-Debug/Debug/Source/CMakeFiles/ProjectB.dir/cmake_pch.hxx:5,
from <command-line>:/home/vsts/work/1/s/ProjectB/Source/stdafx.h:18:10: fatal error: Defs.h: No such file or directory



18 | #include "Defs.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [Source/CMakeFiles/ProjectB.dir/build.make:77: Source/CMakeFiles/ProjectB.dir/cmake_pch.hxx.gch] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:98: Source/CMakeFiles/ProjectB.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
##[error]The process '/usr/local/bin/cmake' failed with exit code 2
##[error]CMake failed with error: The process '/usr/local/bin/cmake' failed with exit code 2

Building in azure devops in Linux envireonment:
Ubuntu: 22.04
Cmake: 3.26
The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
Ninja for build
```

1. I tried adding `/Yc` and `/Yu` compiler options for `stdafx.cpp` and `stdafx.h`.